# Php word replacement

Tags: php, variables, replace, sentence

I'm quite new to **PHP** so I tried to search before I ask this question but I can't find the right answer. Probably because I don't know the right vocabulary.

Anyway here's my problem:

I'm trying to delete a word from sentence. The sentence is a field that can be filled in on the website.

The sentence in **PHP** is:

```
<?php the_field('years'); ?>
```

This works and I get the right sentence. So I tried to replace or hide a word with:

```
<?php 
$sentence = the_field('years');
$test = str_replace('the', ' ', $sentence);
echo "$test"; 
?>
```

But this only echoes the `$sentence` and nothing else.

How to do this? And what is the right word for a 'object' like `"the_field('years')`;?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

The field is actually a [Advanced Custom Field](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) for wordpress.
To get the [Variable](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/code-examples/):

```
  <?php     
$variable = get_field('field_name');    
?>
```

So I tried:

```
<?php 
$sentence = get_field('years');
$test = str_replace('the', ' ', $sentence);
echo "$test"; 
?>
```

But this will echoe: "Array"

Comment: `the_field('years');` is calling a function called the_field with the parameter years. Is this what you want? Maybe you want to get the value of an element in an array, which you can get with $the_field['years'];

Comment: Please, show source of "the_field" function.

Comment: Actually "the_field" echoes an array of fields called 'years'.

Comment: Please see my edit in the post above.

Comment: You cannot use `str_replace` directly on an `array`, show us a sample array

Comment: "the next year is 2014" or "the next year is 2020" are samples. It doesn't matter much. It's a sentence with 'the' in it.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. The array is something like:
the year 2010, the year 2013, the year 2082.
So how to edit words in a array?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the function "the_field" echoes 'years', so you can't store the result in a variable named $sentence since there is no result.
Maybe there is another function that allows you not to echo the result but return it.
From this point, you script should be all right.

Comment: No "the field" echoes a field label called 'years'. In this case it echoes:

The next year is 2014

Edit: Sorry, I think you undestood it right indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you replace the string "the". I don't know the input of `the_field('years')`. But your case works if there is a word called "the".

Please use `var_dump` to determine the value of `the_field('years')`.

Comment: The year 2014, The year 2015NULL is the var_dump

Answer (score 0):

If i am right `str_ireplace` may help you *(Case-insensitive version of `str_replace`)*

```
$test = str_ireplace( 'the', ' ', $sentence );
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried both with the same results.
See my edit above